# iOS [iPhone] plot 2000+ locations on Google Maps

Tags: iphone, ios

I am struggling to plot 2000 store locations on Google maps. I have plotted 10 but then when my client told me that the full dataset has 2000 I am struggling to find the best way to implement this.

The thing is, all 2000 locations don't have to show at once either. When the users GPS is on it will determine where the user is and show the nearest 5 stores.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Using `MKMapView`'s `regionDidChangeAnimated` delegate function, along with `mapView.region`, you can determine the currently visible region of the map.  Dynamically add and remove locations based on this visible region.